# IntelliJ & Eclipse: debug Java application started by Maven exec:exec

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

In my project I have a configuration such as

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions> 
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <commandlineArgs>${additionalExecArgs} -jar ${project.build.directory}/someDir/some.jar</commandlineArgs>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

to start an executable JAR using Maven `exec:exec`.
The `additionalExecArgs` property is empty by default.

In NetBeans I can run this goal by specifying the following action in the `nbactions.xml` file:

```
<action>
    <actionName>run</actionName>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec:exec</goal>   
    </goals>
</action>
```

To debug this goal in NetBeans I've added the following action to the `nbactions.xml` file:

```
<action>
    <actionName>debug</actionName>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec:exec</goal>   
    </goals>
    <properties>
        <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
    </properties>
    <activatedProfiles>
        <activatedProfile>debug</activatedProfile>
    </activatedProfiles>
</action>
```

So in addition to running `exec:exec` it sets the NetBeans (?) property `jpda.listen` to true and activates the Maven profile `debug`.

I've also added the following Maven profile to my POM:

```
<profile>
    <id>debug</id>
    <properties>
        <additionalExecArgs>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</additionalExecArgs>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

With this configuration I can simply run the debug action from the project context menu/ toolbar.

Please note the `jpda.address` Maven property however. This property seems to get populated by NetBeans somehow.

If I try to run `exec:exec` with the debug profile in IntelliJ or Eclipse I'm getting an error, likely because the `jpda.address` Maven property doesn't get set.

E.g. I'm getting the following error in IntelliJ:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:42300,suspend=y,server=n -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar:/opt/idea-IC-141.1010.3/lib/idea_rt.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.1.3 -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/someUser/.m2/repository exec:exec -P debug
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:42300', transport: 'socket'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-application 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default-cli) @ test-application ---
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The port changes with every call.

I've tried and replaced `jpda.address` with a fixed address/ port such as 127.0.0.1:8000, but I'm getting the same error and now in NetBeans, too.

So how can I get a similar behavior in IntelliJ and Eclipse as in NetBeans and debug an `exec:exec` goal using a Maven run configuration directly without having to resort to a remote debugger configuration or such?

Comment: What's wrong with connecting via a remote debugger? This is after all a development environment, and you can launch it with one click after maven exec:exec is up and running.

Comment: @vikingsteve Because you need two clicks (first starting Maven exec:exec, then the remote debugger) in the correct order and maybe also have to switch the current run configuration via drop-down combo box. If you have to do this repeatedly in short intervals this becomes a lot less convenient than the one single click with NetBeans.

Comment: FYI, I filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189973. Anyone interested in this feature should vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can set up a `Remote debug` configuration in intellij with a `Before launch` Maven Goal.

Set it up as follows:

`Run/Debug Configurations` -> Add `Remote` -> Add `Before Launch` -> `Maven` -> specify correct module and goal.

Comment: This sounds like something I was looking for. I will try it out.

Comment: Great. Please let me know how it goes since i did not have time to test it with the exec:exec goal.

Comment: I tried various combinations, but so far I couldn't get it to work.